# Which View does one choose while moving to another Android Activity

Tags: android

After much research and tutorial hunting, I've come to find some answers to questions I had on my own. Now, my last question is this: If I have a `View` instance variable carrying over from the previous `Activity`, and it isn't working to refine the `findViewbyId()` function to the current source file, what should I take my `View` as, to instance my `findViewById()`?

Here's the code I have:

```
public class login_fb extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static AccessToken accessToken = null;
    private static boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    private static String deduction = "";
    private static String income = "";
    private static CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    private static boolean hasItemized = false;
    private FireMissiles fireMissiles = new FireMissiles();

    public void gotoRcpts (View view)
    {
        signIn( view );
    }

    public void getSuggestions(View view) throws ParserConfigurationException, ParseException, SAXException, IOException {
        checkPermsOfStorage( this );
        setContentView( R.layout.content_search );
        Intent intent = Intent.makeMainActivity( lists.newComponentActivity().getComponentName() );
        startActivity( intent );
        lists listing = new lists(view, view.getContext()); //everything works to here.
        listing.display( view );  // This is where I call the function below.
    }
```

Here's the second half of the code

```
public void display(View view)
{
    // I feel the issue is here, but why can I get 
    listViewP = view.findViewById( R.id.view_personal );
    listViewB = view.findViewById( R.id.view_business );
    // now create an adapter class
    Log.d("&&&&", String.valueOf(this.mpTitle.size()));
    if (this.mpTitle != null && listViewP != null) { //if I don't check for null, error
        MyAdapter adapterP = new MyAdapter( this, listed_views, mpTitle, content_search, mContext);
        listViewP.setAdapter( adapterP ); // here's where my error is.
    }
    if (this.mbTitle != null && listViewB != null) { // if I don't check for null error
        MyAdapter adapterB = new MyAdapter( this, listed_views, mbTitle, content_search, mContext);
        listViewB.setAdapter( adapterB ); // here also there's an error.
    }
}
```

The two `ListView`s are `view_personal`, and `view_business`.

Comment: `private FireMissiles fireMissiles = new FireMissiles();` - I am out of here!

Comment: @ReazMurshed I got that straight off of the Google Dev Docs

Answer (score 0):

A `View` is a UI component - when your `Activity` starts, you usually call `setContentView` in `onCreate`, passing in an XML layout file. What that does is construct all the different `View`s in your layout file, setting their parameters, and assigning things like the `id` you've given them.

So you end up with a layout hierarchy, with things like a `TextView` that has an `id` of `titleText` or whatever. You can find that specific object by calling `findViewById()` on a `View` (usually the top-level layout), and it will search all that `View`'s descendants in the layout hierarchy, until it finds one matching that ID name.

Those `View`s are all instances that get created, if you destroy the activity and recreate it you'll have a whole new set of view objects. So you're not keeping instances (and you definitely shouldn't try to either!), and if you go to another `Activity`, you definitely aren't seeing the same view objects again.

---

So when you call `findViewById` in the new activity, using the same `id` as in the last activity, you're not finding the same *instance* of a `View` object - you're just finding one that's been assigned the same ID. You can reuse IDs like this, the only problem is if you have more than one in the same layout hierarchy - `findViewById` will only find the first one that matches.

If you're getting null references for `listViewP` etc., you don't have a view with that ID in your layout (or at least, not under the `View` you're calling `findViewById` on). If they exist in another `Activity`, then you can't access them - that activity isn't running, it doesn't exist. If `ActivityB` wants to change something in `ActivityA`, [it needs to pass data to it](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), so `ActivityA` can handle it.